# Вывести название аудио файла

Tags: php

Есть скрипт загрузки mp3 файлов на сервер. Файл сохраняется и имя ему присваивается рандомно `$name = rand(100, 1654166);`
На сервере файл сохраняется без расширения(т.е. просто цифры)
Возможно ли как нибудь вывести название mp3 файла взяв его из мета-тэгов,например?
И как?
Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: вотч то сказал гугл  https://www.google.ru/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUT_ruRU497RU497&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=php%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20mp3&es_th=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну как-то так:

```
<?php
$f = fopen('test.mp3', 'rb');
rewind($f);
fseek($f, -128, SEEK_END);
$tmp = fread($f,128);
if ($tmp[125] == Chr(0) and $tmp[126] != Chr(0)) {
// ID3 v1.1
$format ='a3TAG/a30NAME/a30ARTISTS/a30ALBUM/a4YEAR/a28COMMENT/x1/C1TRACK/C1GENRENO';
} else {
// ID3 v1
$format = 'a3TAG/a30NAME/a30ARTISTS/a30ALBUM/a4YEAR/a30COMMENT/C1GENRENO';
}
$id3tag = unpack($format, $tmp);
?>
```